# Calculating the area of a triangle

Tags: geometry

Consider the circle of radius $1$ and center in $x=1$, $y=1$. Let $p$ be the point in the circle more close to the origin. Suppose that $p$ is the [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of a triangle with vertex in $(0,1)$, $(2,0)$ and some point $(x,y)$.

My question is: is there any way to calculate the area of the triangle without calculating $(x,y)$, or at least can we give a good approximation for the area?

Thank you

Comment: what did you attempt? write a few lines on how you interpret the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is: first, the circle is $\;(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1\;$ and thus the point on it closer to the origin is on the line $\,y=x\;$ .

Either by substitution or using directly Lagrange's multipliers, get that

$$P=\left(1-\frac1{\sqrt2}\;,\;\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)$$

Since a triangle's centroid is just the triangle's three median's intersection point, the area of the triangle is the length of any side times its distance to the centroid ($\;P\;$) times $\,1.5\;$, so:

(i) Find the formula of the line joining $\,(0,1)\;,\;(2,0)\;$ and the length of this segment

(ii) Calculate the distance from $\;P\;$ to the line above using the formula in (i)

(iii) Multiply the length in (i) by the distance in (ii) and all this times $\,1.5\,$ ...